# Liquid images/tables in ff & ie not liquid

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Having some issues with formatting. I am trying to have a table with two rows and one column. In the top row will be some text. In the bottom row will be a image. I want to have a growing gap between the bottom of the text in the top row and the top of the image in the second row. I also want to have a fixed height of the table to be 250px. I added a border-collapse: separate to the image as I was having issues with FF & IE not wanting to re-size the image to the table but it seems to be removing the gap between the image and text.

A jsFiddle of this is here: http://jsfiddle.net/Qc66W/

I can't seem to find a solution to this. If you could help me out I would greatly appreciate it!!!

```
.HomeWidgetTable {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    width:100%;
    border:0px;
    height:250px;
}
.HomeWidgetTable tr:first-child td{
    text-align:left;
    vertical-align:top;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
.HomeWidgetTable tr:last-child td{
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
.HomeWidgetTable img{
    width:100%;
    border-collapse: separate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this something like you want to achieve? Tables are not needed.

Have a fiddle - [Fiddle Link!](http://jsfiddle.net/Qc66W/1/)

HTML

```
<div class="HomeWidget">
    <p>Text</p>
    <a href="/about/blog/">
        <img src="http://www.warbirdalley.com/images/b25-topsecret1.JPG" />
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.HomeWidget {
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-width: 500px;
    max-width: 800px;
}
.HomeWidget img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I was actualy able to fix my issue with the tables just a few minutes ago (before i saw your reply). Fiddle Link:http://jsfiddle.net/Qc66W/3/
Not sure whether if I should use tables or not but I feel like I am able to get them to format better.

Comment: As far as I can tell you are using tables as a layout tool which is **strongly** discouraged. Using my example you can see how much simpler the markup is in comparison. Less markup = less work.

Comment: I made some changes and was able to get it to work!

    .HomeWidget {
        padding-top: 0;
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        padding-bottom: 0;
    }

    .HomeWidget p {
        margin-top: 0;
        padding-top: 0;
    }

    .HomeWidget img {
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        padding-bottom: 0;
    }

Comment: I thought I had it, but it didn't quite work the way I planned. In the fiddle link below the outer table that houses the three examples of your code are not avoidable. I want the tops of the paragraghs and the tops of the images flush.  
http://jsfiddle.net/Qc66W/6/